# QNetworkAccessManager->get freezes when called in DLL

Tags: c#, c++, qt, dll, qnetworkaccessmanager

I have a dll where I want to do some networking, this dll is called from an C# application as an unmanaged DLL.
All initialization works fine but it freezes everytime the ->get() is supposed to run. I have this code:

```
.........
QUrl path(remotePath);
QNetworkRequest request(path);

currentFile.setFileName(localPath);
if(!currentFile.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly)){
doCallback("failed to open: " + localPath);
}
doCallback("before get: " + remotePath);
QNetworkReply* reply = this->manager->get(request);
doCallback("after get: " + localPath);
...........
```

The "before get" callback is executed fine but never the one "after get" so I guess it completely freezes when manager is trying the Get() method. Have I missed something or is this just plain impossible through an DLL?

Comment: Does the same code work when not called from an unmanaged DLL?  i.e. write a small C++ console application and invoke the same code and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Yes, I created a console application through Qt and then it works fine... I wonder if it could have something to do with that I'm not running any QApplication in my unmanaged DLL but just doing a class call..?

Comment: Okay, so you *didn't* create a native console application and invoked the same code.  If all you invoke in your native application is the posted code and you have the same problem, you know what the issue is.

Comment: Okay, of course. So I need QApplication instantiated and running. But I don't want to exec the QApplication, how can I do this in a DLL, do you know?

Comment: You might have to create an "initialize" function that you can call once from your managed code.  QT is effectively an UI framework and isn't intended to be used with another UI framework or platform.  So, you'll have to go through some hoops like this to get it to work right from managed code.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I exported an init function which creats a QCoreApplication object which my class uses as parent. By .exec the event loop each time I do a new network call I got it working! brilliant!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey so I got this working and I thought I would share my knowledge. With my unmanaged dll I exported an init function which creates a new QCoreApplication, through this I can later use the event loop by using the QCoreApplication object as parent to my class which executes all networking.

```
QCoreApplication* coreApp = 0;
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void initdll()
{
    if (!coreApp) {
        int argc    = 0;
        coreApp = new QCoreApplication(argc, 0);
    }
    if(!MyFunc){
        MyFunc = new QtDll(coreApp);
    }
}
```

By calling this init function in my C# (or whatever) application before I tried any networking I got it working with the code in my first post by adding an exec of the event loop.

```
QNetworkReply* reply = this->manager->get(request);
currentReply = reply;
QEventLoop eLoop;
connect(reply, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(slotReadyRead()));
eLoop.exec( QEventLoop::ExcludeUserInputEvents );
```

Thanks Peter for your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that your QT library was built against opensll.  QNetworkAccessManager looks for the ssl dlls, libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll.  The Win32 LoadLibrary hangs the entire process, UI, signals slots, everything, while it attempts to load these dlls.  Copy these dlls to your executable's directory and the loads will quickly succeed.